# Reference custom style in LaTeX document for docx conversion with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, msword, latex-to-word

I am converting LaTeX documents to MS Word documents using Pandoc. I am using a reference document and I would like to apply styles from that reference document to some elements of the generated Word document.

I found out that this can be done in Pandoc using a custom-style attribute, as described in [the manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles). However, the manual only describes how to reference custom styles from Markdown:

```
[Get out]{custom-style="Emphatically"}, he said.
```

How can I reference custom styles in a LaTeX document? Is this even possible?

Is there something like the following?

```latex
This should be normal text

\begin{customstyle}{Emphatically}
This should be text that is using the Emphatically style
\end{customstyle}
```

Comment: Can you please show us a short TeX code resulting in your issue?

Comment: I've added a snippet of pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve. This issue is not related to an existing piece of code.